# Reactjs: setState from another class or function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Loading component:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Loading extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            display: 'none'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="loading" style={{display: this.state.display}}>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And I want change `display` from `App.js`

```
Loading.setState ...
```

Or

```
var lng = new Loading()
lng.setState ...
```

Both of them not work

I want can change state from another class or function

Comment: Since it would be a child component of App.js, you need to pass down the props

Comment: App.js is a example. maybe i want change it from antoher component. @PrakashS

Comment: I believe you need a better understanding of react. Both the way that you've mentioned doesn't actually represent how a react component should be used.

For this particular case I would advice keeping the state at parent component (`App`) and send the state as prop to the `Loading` component.
`<Loading display={display} />`

Comment: @parkourkarthik App.js is a example. maybe i want change it from antoher component.

Comment: Then a global state manager library like `redux` would help

Comment: @FAcademy: In the question you specify the `App` component.  If you now want to change it from a different component, please update the question to indicate that and specify how those components relate to one another.  Is this new "other component" a parent component of `Loading`?  A child component of `Loading`?  Something else?  Where are you maintaining this state value and what is stopping you from passing it as a property to any given child component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change `display` from `App.js`:

1. Pass it as prop to `Loading` component, and keep the state at `App.js`.
2. pass some prop from `App.js` and when it changes - change the state
   of `display` in `App.js`
3. Use some global state/store manager like [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) or built-in [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) react-hook, in this case you will be able to change from any component connected to store

Comment: If i want change from another class? except for App.js ?

Comment: Then option number 3

Comment: Thank you. can you send me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

[Solution sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-mccarthy-xf98m?file=/src/App.js:0-485)

A simple solution can be found in a code sandbox example.